# Mysql joining two tables where part of string in table1 are in table2

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am currently developing an employee database website. Previously my client use ms. excel as database storage which has no structure. But they already have thousands of data. I have already imported data into temporary tables. The problem is, I had to adjust the excel data with database structure.

This is my tables structure :

```
ms_absen :

id      name
------------------------
11      vnice ardian
22      setiawan ecco
33      andytaman1
44      rusdytaman2

ms_employee :

id_emp    name          
---------------------------
01        ardiansyah       
02        setiawan thea    
03        arif andy syah   
04        jonathan         
05        f rusdy          

expected result :

id_emp    name               id
--------------------------------------
01        ardiansyah         11
02        setiawan thea      22
03        arif andy syah     33
05        rusdy              44
```

This is what I have tried so far,

```
select e.id_emp,e.name,a.id
from ms_employee as e
inner join ms_absen a
on a.name like concat('%',left(e.name,3),'%')
```

This return only `ardiansyah, setiawan thea and rusdy` instead of all employees except jonathan. Please note that I use `inner join` rather than `left join`, because I want to eliminated employes that `not in ms_absen` table.

Comment: You are going to have to manually go in an fix the names.  In Excel, add another column for the employee id and start working on inputing it.  From what I can see, the strings are just to different to figure out any rules.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Don't you have another tips instead of manually fix the names on excel? Excel data has thousands rows.

Comment: I really don't.  You can download a function for Levenshtein distance (google:  "mysql levenshtein").  That might do a pretty good job of finding the nearest match.  What does "arif andy syah" have to do with "andytaman1" ?  Your client really needs to fix the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your suggestions, I'll try mysql levenshtein to solve this problem. But i need to keep this question open and any suggestion are very welcome.

Comment: Is there and if is than what is the pattern of mapping the names? Because your condition `concat('%',left(e.name,3),'%')` clearly is not universal e.g. `f rusdy` will result in searching for `f r` in the first table.

Comment: @zmii Thanks for reply. My condition `concat('%',left(e.name,3),'%')` actually didn't return rusdy in resultset. And that was the problem : there is no pattern of mapping the names. It's random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given we have data presented in the question we can write something like this:

1. This will result in a table with 3 columns. Let's assume the resulting table will be called A.

   SELECT
   id,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'name' , ' ', 1 ) AS a,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'name' , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1) AS b
   FROM ms_absen
2. This is pseudo (i haven't tested it) code that shows the idea.

   select e.id_emp, e.name, a.id
   from ms_employee as e, A as a
   where e.name like concat('%',left(a.part1,3),'%')
   or    e.name like concat('%',left(a.part2,3),'%')

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try it and will be back to give some feedback.

Comment: I don't actually try this, but i got clue from your answer to solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't map one thing to another ( or join in your state ) without having a mapping ).

If I were you I would try to map one of the tables to other table with good data and then apply something like you've specified

```
select e.id_emp,e.name,a.id
from ms_employee as e
inner join ms_absen a
on a.name like concat('%',left(e.name,3),'%')
```

Question is - how to transform your data into good one?

You see, you have a spaces in this name column. And if you had no spaces, then it would be easier. So you map one table to some transition table with columns `id, name_part1, name_part2, ..., name_partN`, where `N` is the maximum number of words in name ( finding this `N` can be done manually ). Then you can apply logic alike this one ([this is the comment to MySQL documentation on string built-in functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)):

```
// Posted by [name withheld] on March 22 2006 8:02pm

// This will split an IP address ("a.b.c.d") into 4 respective octets:

SELECT
`ip` ,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', 1 ) AS a,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1) AS b,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', -2 ),'.',1) AS c,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ip` , '.', -1 ) AS d
FROM log_table
```

Thus you will have a table where every column `nameX` where `X` is inside range `1...N`.

This is the best I can suggest you for now without using RDBMS )

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Can you show me how to implement this to my issue?